# Gradle error code (when compiling Android SDK sample): 139

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Trying to compile the Android SDK sample (using Gradle 1.10 at the command line level, no Eclipse or Android Studio or any IDE involved)):

android-sdk-linux/samples/android-19/ui/AdapterTransition/AdapterTransitionSample>

I got the following errors:

```
gradle build --stacktrace
:AdapterTransitionSample:compileDebugNdk
:AdapterTransitionSample:preBuild
:AdapterTransitionSample:preDebugBuild
:AdapterTransitionSample:checkDebugManifest
:AdapterTransitionSample:prepareDebugDependencies
:AdapterTransitionSample:compileDebugAidl
:AdapterTransitionSample:compileDebugRenderscript
:AdapterTransitionSample:generateDebugBuildConfig
:AdapterTransitionSample:mergeDebugAssets
:AdapterTransitionSample:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:AdapterTransitionSample:generateDebugResources
:AdapterTransitionSample:mergeDebugResources
:AdapterTransitionSample:processDebugManifest
:AdapterTransitionSample:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':AdapterTransitionSample:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /opt/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-19/android.jar -M /sda1/android-sdk-linux/samples/android-19/ui/AdapterTransition/AdapterTransitionSample/build/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /sda1/android-sdk-linux/samples/android-19/ui/AdapterTransition/AdapterTransitionSample/build/res/all/debug -A /sda1/android-sdk-linux/samples/android-19/ui/AdapterTransition/AdapterTransitionSample/build/assets/debug -m -J /sda1/android-sdk-linux/samples/android-19/ui/AdapterTransition/AdapterTransitionSample/build/source/r/debug -F /sda1/android-sdk-linux/samples/android-19/ui/AdapterTransition/AdapterTransitionSample/build/libs/AdapterTransitionSample-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.example.android.adaptertransition
  Error Code:
    139


* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':AdapterTransitionSample:processDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:289)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$1.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:198)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:266)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:95)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /opt/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-19/android.jar -M /sda1/android-sdk-linux/samples/android-19/ui/AdapterTransition/AdapterTransitionSample/build/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /sda1/android-sdk-linux/samples/android-19/ui/AdapterTransition/AdapterTransitionSample/build/res/all/debug -A /sda1/android-sdk-linux/samples/android-19/ui/AdapterTransition/AdapterTransitionSample/build/assets/debug -m -J /sda1/android-sdk-linux/samples/android-19/ui/AdapterTransition/AdapterTransitionSample/build/source/r/debug -F /sda1/android-sdk-linux/samples/android-19/ui/AdapterTransition/AdapterTransitionSample/build/libs/AdapterTransitionSample-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.example.android.adaptertransition
Error Code:
    139

    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:66)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:236)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:212)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:223)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:533)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:516)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.0.3/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /opt/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-19/android.jar -M /sda1/android-sdk-linux/samples/android-19/ui/AdapterTransition/AdapterTransitionSample/build/manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /sda1/android-sdk-linux/samples/android-19/ui/AdapterTransition/AdapterTransitionSample/build/res/all/debug -A /sda1/android-sdk-linux/samples/android-19/ui/AdapterTransition/AdapterTransitionSample/build/assets/debug -m -J /sda1/android-sdk-linux/samples/android-19/ui/AdapterTransition/AdapterTransitionSample/build/source/r/debug -F /sda1/android-sdk-linux/samples/android-19/ui/AdapterTransition/AdapterTransitionSample/build/libs/AdapterTransitionSample-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package com.example.android.adaptertransition
Error Code:
    139

    at com.android.ide.common.internal.CommandLineRunner.runCmdLine(CommandLineRunner.java:98)
    at com.android.ide.common.internal.CommandLineRunner.runCmdLine(CommandLineRunner.java:69)
    at com.android.builder.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:768)
    at com.android.builder.AndroidBuilder$processResources.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.groovy:99)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.groovy:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    ... 57 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.57 secs
```

The "build.gradle" file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19

    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"
```

the above version was changed from 19.0.1 to 19.0.2 to 19.0.3, but have the same erro.

Please advise?

Comment: @scott, thanks for the reference, ONE of the suggestion in your link solved the problem, as detailed below.

Comment: @matiash, sorry, I did not use Android Studio from the start.   It is just direct compiling Android SDK using Gradle 1.10 downloaded.